# Github team repository

Tags: github

I started working on an app with my girlfriend and I have created the repository. The problem is that she is the collaborator, but she wants to pin the repository to her profile. Is it possible for her to have the same version of the repository as I do and that it is synced (she wants to see it on her profile)

We checked on git forking but it said that it will disconnect the codebase from previous committers. Also, if she clones the project she won't have the repository shown on her profile.

On the other hand, if I set the auto-merge option to true will it solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If she is listed as a contributor on the repo after a PR or a direct push she should be able to select the repo from the list:

[image]

This is my list, there are many repos I don't even have direct write permissions to.